# Containers versus components versus controls (general UI library design)

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm developing a user interface framework in Java.  It's not a very serious one but i'm still putting some effort into doing this in a good way.

I have a small design issue regarding containers.  In my design I have `Control` which is the base class for all UI elements.  It has fields for size, position and methods for rendering etc..

Then there is `Container` which can hold a group of controls.  For example a list box has contains multiple controls.  `Container` is a subclass of `Control`.  It simply adds methods for accessing the child controls, e.g. `Container.renderChildren()` .

That is all good, but it means `Container` needs to hold 2 lists.  One list for the plain old `Control`s and one list for `Container`s that it holds.  You can't really put them into a single `List<Control> childList;` because containers have additional functionality.  They need to be treated differently than plain controls.

So I decided to introduce `Component` which holds either a Control or a Container, with a flag saying which one it holds.  Then every Container just has a single list of Components, and Component takes care of abstracting away the differences between Control and Container.  For example there is a Component.renderChildren() which calls the appropriate method.

The problem is it doesn't seem very elegant.  It feels like a work-around for inheritance issues.  At first I just made every Control have container-like functionality, so all controls are able to hold child controls.  But I also don't like that because a Control shouldn't know anything about children, it should just be a simple UI element.

I refreshed my knowledge on how C# does it.  In C# component is effectively a subclass of control, rather than the other way around.  But I also don't like that.

I apologize for the poorly phrased and long winded question.  I didn't put much effort in because it's a fairly minor issue but interested in hearing thoughts if you yourself could be bothered.

```
public class Control {
    public Dimensions dimensions;

    public void render() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Container extends Control {
    protected ControlList childControls;
    protected ContainerList childContainers;

    public ControlList getRenderList() {
        // return all children (both controls and containers) 
        // ...
    }
}

public class Renderer {
    // container for main window that holds the 'tree' of all other controls
    protected Container rootContainer;

    public void render() {
        ControlList renderList = rootContainer.getRenderList();

        // do the render
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `Component` certainly sounds like a bad design choice. It's just a very roundabout way of doing `instanceof`. `instanceof` is bad but this is just the same thing only more long-winded. `renderChildren` sounds kind of suspect to me. What's wrong with just a single generic `render` method, where the `Control` decides whether or not to render any children it may have?

Comment: I agree Michael, I like to avoid instanceof if possible, that would probably be my last choice if pushed.  But my design doesn't smell much better which is why I wonder still.  If you do a generic render() it means it has to give back a list (for Container) rather than a single item (for Control).  That is the core problem here, the subclass needs to return a list but the base class should only know about a singular item.

Comment: I agree again, updated the main post.

Comment: I still don't see why Container needs `getRenderList`. Container should override `render` and loop through all of the children, calling `render` on each. This eliminates the need for a Container to have special behaviour (it needn't).

Comment: What you're trying to implement is called a ['scene graph'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph). I would also strongly suggest you use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: This isn't just about rendering, there are many other facets to controls that i haven't included (mouseover, user input, modal states etc.).  Scene graphs don't solve itand I'm virtually doing one anyway (i.e. using a display list).  Composition is arguable, there are a lot of cases where it just causes more boilerplate without any benefit.  That being said I use it but in this case I don't see how it helps much.  For the previous comment about 'render()', i described why that is no elegant already.  It means Control.render() needs to return a list, it shouldn't know about those.

Comment: "Control.render() needs to return a list". That method doesn't return *anything* in the code that you've provided. I can only work with the code you've given me. I'm not psychic. Your question is very broad and I don't think anyone will be able to answer it to your satisfaction because there simply is not enough information.

Comment: Sorry I meant Container.getRenderList().  Control.getRenderList() isn't needed because there's just one control to render (no children).